# Modify old release on Github for pushing out a patch

Tags: git, github

Say I have various tags / releases, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3. Master branch is currently the bleeding edge, in preparation for 1.1.0.

I now realize that I need to push a small patch, 1.0.4.

What's the best way to make the patch based off of 1.0.3, push it to github, tag it as 1.0.4, but then still keep master branch at the bleeding edge and preparation for 1.1.0?

EDIT:
Repository in question (note, it's actually v1.0.5 -> v1.0.6): https://github.com/brashrebel/render

Comment: I think taking a look at the repository in question could be helpful, if that's possible.

Comment: You really should consider using a workflow [like this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). This will enable you to easily manage releases without worrying about having to release a hotfix while working on a major release.

Comment: I will definitely read that and consider implementing it.

Answer (score 5):

I would say you have two possibilities: one leaving 1.0.4 as a dangling commit in its own branch, and another one rebasing all of your later commits on top of that new branch, and then discarding it.

The first would mean:

```
$ git checkout v1.0.3
$ git checkout -b patch-for-1.0.4
# ... edit files ...
$ git commit -a -m 'Patch for 1.0.4'
$ git tag v1.0.4
```

After this, your tag `v1.0.4` is not in the `master` branch, but it is findable in the repo and you can make a release out of it.  You only have to be careful not to remove the branch `patch-for-1.0.4`.

The second would mean do the aforementioned, and then continue to:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rebase patch-for-1.0.4
# ... solve conflicts ...
$ git branch -d patch-for-1.0.4
```

This assumes that all commits working from 1.0.3 towards 1.1.0 have been done on master.  If you expect many conflicts, you may want to test this first on a branch made right off master, or do an `--interactive` rebase.

This second alternative is cleaner, and you can remove the `patch-for-v1.0.4` branch; but it entails rebasing old commits on top of newer ones, and this is something that not everyone feels comfortable doing, specially if you are working in a team.

**EDIT**:

This is your starting situation:

```
A -------- B - C - D  ( ... will become v1.1.0)
(v1.0.3)
```

The first snippet creates a patch and leaves it as a dangling commit in its own branch:

```
A -------- B - C - D
\
 --- E
     (v1.0.4)
```

If you do a merge at this point, you will get:

```
A --------- B - C - D --------- E
(v1.0.3)            (v1.1.0)    (v1.0.4)
```

In order to avoid that `E` is put on top of the `B - C - D` commits, do a rebase:

```
A --------- E ------- B' - C' - D'
(v.1.0.3)  (v1.0.4)             (v1.1.0)
```

Note that this changes commits `B - C - D` to `B' - C' - D'`, which have the same contents (except for conflict fixes), but different hashes, because they are now on top of `E`, not `A`.  This may break the `master` branch of other people on your team, or their feature branches, but leaves things in their logical order.

Comment: I guess our differences stem from the fact that in git, history doesn't have to be "in order". Branches can start and merge at any time. Why would you care that "E is on top"? All you have to care about is that E is in the fixed version as well as in the coming releases (`v1.1.0` and later). What if in B, C, D are ten other releases? That are GPG signed? You should **not** rebase here if it is the tiniest bit more than your own toy project.

Comment: @musiKk : I don't agree with that point.  If file `X` is added (or public API `Y` is altered) on commit B, then release 1.0.4 **will contain** those changes if you merge commit E after commit B.  And well, rebases are not a toy, specially on a master branch; there I agree. I'm showing here how to accomplish an operation, but it is up to the OP to know if it is acceptable in his situation or not.

Comment: This is not true. In fact, your merge picture is wrong. A merge introduces an additional commit, say M, that joins master and fix branch. And in no case does the tag `v1.0.4` "move" like you show it.

Comment: @musiKk I'm sorry if I sounded aggressive.  I'm open to being corrected.  But I just made the experiment on a local git repository, and yes, my merge picture is right -- there is a merge commit, but E is put **after** B, C and D.  You can check it on this Gist: https://gist.github.com/logc/21450abfa3000897f8cf

Comment: You don't sound aggressive. My assumption is that you do a `git checkout master; git merge E`. If that's the case, the image certainly is not right. E and D would both lead to a new merge commit M. You have to look at the output of `git log --graph` if you want to see that. `git log` output is always linear but that doesn't mean that the history is linear. (Don't know if it's in the example as I find it hard to read. It's very noisy and I don't know your aliases.)

Comment: @musiKk : I cleaned up the Gist, and added the graph of `git log --graph`. But the point is `cat main.py`: merging makes appear many functions that were added for 1.1.0.  Maybe we can move this discussion to the Gist, if you want? Otherwise, let's agree to disagree :)

Comment: I guess we can sum it up. The graph you show for the merge case is exactly what I think is the best solution. The only thing that's missing is the actual tag but that's trivial to add. It boils down to best practices: You never rebase mainline and you never rebase branches with tags. You *can* rebase feature branches, although I'm not too big a fan of that either. That's my stance and I've never seen anything else.

Answer (score 4):

You check out the commit you want to base your patch on. You do what's necessary, create your commits, tag the result and push. In order to get them into your mainline you can either cherry-pick those commits or merge the branch back.

Now, it might be a bit awkward if the new tag is not on a branch. I certainly have never seen a branch that is only reachable by a tag. So my personal recommendation would be to merge the branch back.

To be a bit more concrete:

```
$ git checkout -b v1.0.5_fixes v1.0.5    # create a bugfix branch
# ... do some work ...
# ... make commits ...
$ git tag v1.0.6
$ git checkout master
$ git merge v1.0.5_fixes     # merge back, solve merge conflicts if any
$ git branch -d v1.0.5_fixes # delete the branch, it's not needed anymore
```

Comment: Is it maybe `git merge v1.0.5_fixes` on line 6? `v1.0.5` should already be in `master` ... Otherwise, by merging that branch back in `master` without a rebase, wouldn't the change for 1.0.5 be "on top" of those for 1.0.6?

Comment: @logc Yes, `v1.0.5_fixes`, thanks. A rebase is not a good way to solve this problem in my opinion. I'm not sure what you mean by "on top". `v1.0.5` is a release, a few fixes added and it becomes `v1.0.6`.

Comment: @logc - musiKk has it described perfectly IMO - rebase should not to be used at all in this scenario. (edit - woops, I see that there was an edit that caused comment confusion)

Comment: Maybe I am wrong.  I added some graphs to my answer in order to explain how I see the situation. But please correct me if I am wrong -- today I am really exhausted :)